# wxPython caret move event

Tags: python, events, wxpython, wxwidgets

What event is called when the caret inside a TextCtrl / Styled TextCtrl has its position changed? I need to bind the event to show in the status bar, the current position of the caret.

Comment: Tried wx.stc.EVT_STC_CHANGE, good when I'm changing the content, but no good when I'm just simply moving the caret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding the `wx.EVT_KEY_UP` event with the `wx.TextCtrl` object like this:

```
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Show Caret Position", size=(400, 140))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Text:", (10, 22))
        self.textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(
                panel,
                -1, "",
                (50,5),
                size=(250, 50),
                style=wx.TE_MULTILINE
            )
        self.textCtrl.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        self.textCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP,self.onTextKeyEvent)
        self.textCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP,self.onTextKeyEvent)
        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar(1)
        panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer, wx.VERTICAL)

    def onTextKeyEvent(self, event):
        statusText = "Caret Position: "+str(self.textCtrl.GetInsertionPoint())
        self.SetStatusText(statusText,0)
        event.Skip()


#Run application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I've tested on `Windows 7` environment with `Python 2.7` + `wxPython 2.8`.

[image: Here is how it should look like]

Comment: Yes, it worked well with keyboard, thank you very much. But when I change the position of the caret using mouse, it ain't working right.

Comment: Ohh --- I forgot to add the `MouseEvent` for the `TextCtrl`, just add the line `self.textCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP,self.onTextKeyEvent)' after the line `self.textCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP,self.onTextKeyEvent)'. It'll work on mouse clicks.

Comment: On my install, this doesn't work (and shouldn't work if I read the documentation correctly). `OnKeyUp` is called BEFORE the cursor moves, so `GetInsertPoint` will always return the position of the cursor before the movement, not after.  This can be worked around with some code, but definitely an area of improvement for wxWidgets.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with @Tariq M Nasim code is that it actually gives you last position not current caret position. The simplest way I found is to post new event while the event chain already exists so the new event is handled as the last one in queue:

```
# create event class as global
import wx.lib.newevent
SomeNewEvent, EVT_SOME_NEW_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

# then bind the events in the constructor or somewhere
self.text_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.onKeyDownHandler)
self.text_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onKeyDownHandler)
self.text_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_UP, self.onKeyDownHandler)
# bind also new event handler but 
self.text_ctrl.Bind(EVT_SOME_NEW_EVENT , self.onKeyDownAction)

# then define the handlers
def onKeyDownAction(self, evt):
    print("Insertion point {}".format(self.text_ctrl.GetInsertionPoint()))
    evt.Skip()

def onKeyDownHandler(self, evt):
    evt.Skip()
    # post the new event so it will be handled later
    wx.PostEvent(self.text_ctrl, SomeNewEvent())
```

This way the insertion point you get in onKeyDownAction is proper.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such an event, but you can try wx.EVT_SET_CURSOR. Alternatively, you can catch wx.EVT_CHAR or one of the EVT_KEY_* events and use the TextCtrl's GetInsertionPoint() method to know where the cursor is. You may need to call the method when you click around in the text control using mouse events as well.

Comment: wx.EVT_SET_CURSOR caused my pointer not to transform into that 'I' letter like thing. Is there other method that can be used without preventing the mouse from transforming?

Comment: I probably should have said you could use wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN instead of the cursor one. Try that.

Comment: It successfully didn't stop my mouse pointer's transformation, but it need double click to move the caret using mouse now...

Comment: Funny enough is that now the StatusBar is delayed by 1 turn. Let's say I choose in order, Line 1 Col 2, Line 3 Col 2, Line 1 Col 8. It shows Line 1 Col 2 for the first 2 caret position change, when I do the third, it shows Line 3 Col 2. However, if I use keyboard to move the caret, it shows the right Line and Col number.

Comment: You probably needed to call event.Skip() so you don't need to double-click.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll & Tendo Kishi: using **`wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN`** is not the solution here... have to use **`wx.EVT_LEFT_UP`** instead. See my code above.

Comment: What's the difference between LEFT_DOWN and LEFT_UP?

Comment: `wx.EVT_XXX_DOWN` is generated whn the Mouse/Key is at the **clicking/pressed position** and `wx.EVT_XXX_UP` is generated whn the Mouse/Key is **released**. The ui doesn't change immediately after `wx.EVT_XXX_DOWN` events are generated, so the caret position we show on the status bar doesn't get changed immediately too, but the UI changes immediately after the `wx.EVT_XXX_UP` event is generated. <--- I don't have good explanation why this happens, I just have noticed this.

Comment: Partially related to: DOWN events are recurrent so long as a key is down. UP events are one-offs. Once you release a key you don't keep getting key UP events for each key that is not held down.

Comment: Testing your issue I too came across the delay on EVT_KEY_DOWN. I too noticed the wx.Frame.SetStatusText(text, index) one message behind) in the field indexes 1 and above. But Field 0 updates right way. Additionally I think there is a forced delay from first key down event to second downkey event for the "key auto-repeat" processes. The EVT_KEY_UP does not have "key auto-repeat". This is an issue to getting updated x,y info while moving around wx.TextCtrl-like widgets. I'll mess around where I bind and handle those events. Perhaps I'll bind it to a custom Statusbar. Made any process yourself?

Comment: After further testing with the EVT_KEY_UP event, this seems to have solved the issue with the statusbar updates lagging one keystroke behind as seen with the EVT_KEY_DOWN event. It works but I couldn't say how logically.

Answer (score 0):

In order to know when mouse is placed inside any window you can bind wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW (see [here](https://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.MouseEvent-class.html))